# Using pip in the standalone Spyder on MacOS

Tags: python, pip, spyder

As the Anaconda Distribution of Spyder has some typing latency issues on macOS Big Sur, I've gone ahead and downloaded the standalone distribution. However, when trying to install packages with pip I get the error message:

```
pip install numpy
/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No module named pip
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

(I know that NumPy is already installed - this just serves as an example). I have Anaconda installed, and there pip works fine. How do I install it for the specific Standalone Distribution?

Comment: (*Spyder  maintainer here*) Hey Christian, if you want to use other modules that don't come with our installer, please go [here](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) to learn how to connect our installer to Anaconda.

Comment: We don't (and won't) provide `pip` as part of our installer to avoid people breaking Spyder by installing conflicting or problematic packages. That's a common issue for many people and the reason why we decided to create our installer in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the Command Prompt and typing `pip install -U spyder`. If you don't have the "standalone version" of Python, just install it to have access to this command.

After that, you can simply open Spyder typing in the Command Prompt `spyder`.